# Does this sequence of operators converge uniformly?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be orthonormal sets (not necessarily maximal). Consider the operators $T_n$ defined by

$$T_nu=(x_n|u)y_n.$$

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n$ converge uniformly? I.e., does the sequence of partial sums $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n T_n$ converge in the operator norm of $\mathfrak B(H)$?

---

I'm asking because the book I am reading (V. Moretti, *Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics*) casually mentions that **if** such a series converges uniformly, then the limit is a compact operator [Example 4.16 (2)]. But I am curious whether such a series must always converge uniformly anyway.

Comment: Does $\left( x_n ! u \right)$ mean $\left\langle x_n, u \right\rangle$?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Yes, I am using Moretti's notation of $(\cdot | \cdot )$ for inner products.

Comment: You can also notice that expected limit is a unitary isomorphism between closed separable infinite dimensional subspaces of $H$. So it can’t be compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k, n$ be natural and $||u|| = 1$. We have
$$\left|\left|\sum_{m=n}^{k+n}(x_m, u)y_n\right|\right|^2 =  \sum_{m=n}^{k+n}|(x_m,u)|^2 \to 0,$$
when $n \to \infty$, because we can extend $\{x_n\}$ to a basis. But this sum has a maximal value $1$ (by the Bessel inequality) for any $n$ and $k$. Moreover, when $u \in \mathop{span}(x_n, \dots, x_{n+k})$ this value is achieved. In other words, $||S_{n+k} - S_{n}|| = 1$ for all $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this answers the question.

Comment: Also I don't think your assertion about $\{x_n\}$ being maximal is correct.

Comment: @WillG yeah, I have made an edit

Comment: Your last sentence still seems incorrect. Also we cannot only restrict our attention to the span of $\{x_n\}$ as you seem to have done.

Comment: @WillG I just gave an example when $||(S_{n+k} - S_n)u|| = ||u||$, which means $||S_{n+k}-S_n|| \geq 1||. The inverse inequality is provided by the formula above.

Comment: Ok now I see your point. So if this is true, then the series can never converge uniformly?

Comment: @WillG Unless this is not an infinite series at all, i.e. the space is finite dimensional. Another explanation of this phenomenon I gave in the comment. It relies on the fact that infinite-dimensional sphere (or ball) is not compact. A dimensionality is essential here.